# How to get ALL minimal set covers?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, set-cover

Set cover algorithms tend to provide just one solution for finding a minimum number of sets to cover. How to go about finding all such solutions?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35475/how-to-enumerate-minimal-covers-of-a-set

Comment: Thanks, though it just converts into another problem and I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "minimal" as this will vary the number of set covers you get. For example if you had the target set of `ABC` and the sets `AB`,`AC`,`C` to choose from you could cover with either (`AB`,`C`) or (`AB`,`AC`) or all 3 (`AB`,`AC`,`C`) and if you're defining "minimal" as for example the 2 lowest choices i.e. with the fewest overlaps or fewest repeated elements then you would choose the 1st 2 ((`AB`,`C`) and (`AB`,`AC`)). "Minimal" could also be defined in terms number of sets chosen so for the above example the lowest number would be 2 and either (`AB`,`C`) or (`AB`,`AC`) would work. But if you wanted all possible set covers you could start with just brute force going through each combo so

```java
import java.util.*;
public class f {

    // abcd
    static int target = 0b1111;
    // ab,ac,acd,cd
    static int[] groups = {0b1100,0b1010,0b1011,0b0011};

    // check if sets cover target
    // for example 1100 and 0011 would cover 1111
    static boolean covers(boolean[] A){
        int or = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if(A[i]) or = or | groups[i];
        }
        int t = target;
        while (t>0){
            if(t%2!=1 || or%2!=1)
                return false;
            t = t>>1;
            or = or>>1;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // go through all choices
    static void combos(boolean A[],int i,int j){
        if(i>j){
            if(covers(A)) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
            return;
        }
        combos(A,i+1,j);
        A[i]=!A[i];
        combos(A,i+1,j);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean[] A = new boolean[groups.length];
        combos(A,0,groups.length-1);
    }
}
```